# my codeblock doesn't compile

Tags: c, debugging, compilation, codeblocks

Sorry for my broken English.

I'm pretty new to coding. I installed codeblock a couple weeks ago and today it stopped compiling. At first I deactivated Norton security and it worked. But now even I deactivated Norton, it doesn't compile. I googled for more than 1 hour but I have no idea what is wrong.

When I compile, statement like below pops up.

```
-------------- Build file: Debug in work place (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall -g  -c "C:\Users\(myname\Desktop\folder's name\work place\Untitled1.c" -o obj\Debug\Untitled1.o
Process terminated with status 0 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

Please help me!

*) I didn't post the original code I tried to compile because it is too simlple. But maybe I have to.

```
#include <stdio.h>
 int main(){
   int a, b;
   a=4;
   b=3;
   printf("%d %d", a, b);

    return 0;
   }
```

***) I guess I solved the problem. I reinstalled the codeblocks.

Comment: No offence but is there something wrong with my question? Why down vote?

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I also recommend you read [this Stack Overflow question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And *all* of http://idownvotedbecau.se/ to learn some of the many reasons you get down-votes.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude No offence but I still don't understand. I know my question seems stupid, but I'm pretty new to coding. I really tried to figure out what's wrong with codeblock, googled for more than 1 hour. Anyway, sorry if my question was inappropriate.

Comment: When you get a status 0 this means it was uneventful, so no issue. You should find that obj\Debug\Untitled1.o exists. Did you try to 'Run' it from codeblock? Is there an error then? If you solved it, I suggest you answer your own question and mark it as the answer.

Comment: It does compile, the message says everything went well. Could you tell us exactly what happens when you click the "Build and Run" button?

Comment: @Carol I reinstalled codeblocks and now it seems OK. As you said, maybe there was no problem in the first place. I'm new to coding. Thanks!

Comment: @FeiXiang Thanks a lot for your comment. In hindsight maybe it was OK. I guess I was just stressed out yesterday. I'm just a beginner so I make a lot of mistakes. Thanks again!

Comment: @Carol you suggested me answer my own question but I'm not very sure if just reinstalling could be a proper answer.. Thanks a lot for your kind comment!

Comment: No I guess we could probably close this question as we will never really know what happened. Have fun learning :)

Answer (score 0):

I just reinstalled the codeblocks and now it seems OK. I guess there was no problem in the place...